# How to change logo of payment option in WooCommerce / WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, hook-woocommerce

I have a plugin called `WooCommerce PayPal Payments` which allows `PayPal` payments in `WooCommerce`. With this plugin, they also have an option for `credit card` payments. See below:

[image]

All of this renders the following on the front end:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to change the `AMEX` logo to a custom logo.

I've seen many articles which show how to change the `PayPal` logo, [such as this one](https://www.themelocation.com/how-to-replace-default-paypal-logo-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/), but haven't seen any that mention how to change the AMEX, MasterCard or other logo.

For example, I've used this hook to change the `PayPal` logo:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'remove_what_is_paypal', 10, 2 );

function remove_what_is_paypal( $icon_html, $gateway_id ) {
  if( 'paypal' == $gateway_id ) {
    $paypal_logo = get_template_directory_uri()."/assets/build/vectors/paypal-logo-original.svg";
    $icon_html = "<img class='checkoutPage__paypal' src=".$paypal_logo."' alt='PayPal logo'>";
  }
  return $icon_html;
}
```

How do I change the `AMEX` logo?

Comment: Consider using https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/ instead, which supports current PayPal Checkout integrations and an advanced hosted field integration for the credit card form ( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/ , not sure how it's styled in woocommerce but will likely be better than the old module you're using )

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX - The plugin you have linked is the plugin I have installed and am using currently already

Comment: Doesn't look good to me, not sure if your site's theme or they just didn't do a good job with it. Anyway, in your function, temporarily set `return $gateway_id . $icon_html` , then you'll know what gateway_id to target in an `else if` statement.

Comment: I have had a look at the plugins code, and there doesn' appear to be any filters that allow you to change the logo. The best I could suggest is to change the source asset referred to in wp-content\plugins\woocommerce-paypal-payments\modules\ppcp-wc-gateway\services.php on line 295 which is assets/images/amex.svg Obviously this is far from ideal as it would mean that it would get replaced whenever the plugin is updated.

Comment: Please share the website URL

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('clean_url', 'custom_clean_url', 10, 3);

function custom_clean_url($good_protocol_url, $original_url, $_context) {


    if (strpos($good_protocol_url, 'assets/images/amex.svg') !== false) {
        return 'https://woocommerce.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/assets/images/cards/amex.svg';
    }
    return $good_protocol_url;
}
```

Change the return URL as per the requirement.

There is no filter in the plugin to the cards array to change the icon for individuals. AFAIK this is the only hook that can be used in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'custom_payment_gateway_icons', 10, 2 );
function custom_payment_gateway_icons( $icon, $gateway_id ){

    foreach( WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways() as $gateway )
        if( $gateway->id == $gateway_id ){
            $title = $gateway->get_title();
            break;
        }

    // The path (subfolder name(s) in the active theme)
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets';

    // Setting (or not) a custom icon to the payment IDs
    
    if($gateway_id == 'paypal_payment_id')
        $icon = '<img src="' . WC_HTTPS::force_https_url( "https://website.com/logo.png" ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '" />';
    

    return $icon;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not, apparently, a filter for altering this gateway's html, or specifically the credit card icons, you might have to resort to a CSS kludge.

You could use the following code to hide or cover the AMEX image, and replace it with the same image as pseudo-element background. Replacing it with some different image would be as simple as replacing the background-image url with the one you want to use:

```
/** CSS KLUDGE VS WOOCOMMERCE PAYPAL PAYMENTS CREDIT CARD ICONS **/
#payment .payment_methods .payment_method_ppcp-credit-card-gateway {
     position: relative;
}
#payment .payment_methods .payment_method_ppcp-credit-card-gateway:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 205px;    
    height: 22px;
    width: 35px;
    background-size: cover;
    /* replace URL here */
    background-image: url(/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/modules/ppcp-wc-gateway/assets/images/amex.svg);
}
#payment .payment_methods .payment_method_ppcp-credit-card-gateway img[title="American Express"] { 
    display: none;
}
```

I'd wait to apply the last line, which may not even be necessary, until I'd finished making position and size nudges to get the new image looking just right. Naturally, you'd want to double check against unique theme characteristics and for responsiveness, but anyway there's the concept.